# Jquery hide and show content in div on hover errors on fast mouse movement

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with menu buttons using jquery to show and hide two images in the button on mouseover. If a user mouses in and then out before the animation is complete both images will show.

Jsfiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/wckilby/d8wrs1gf/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="flag" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/flag-icon.svg">
  <img id="name" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/cftp-logo.svg">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "#wrapper" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( "#flag" ).fadeOut(150);
    $( "#wrapper" ).css("width", "360px");
    $( "#name" ).delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });
  $( "#wrapper" ).mouseleave(function() {
     $( "#name" ).hide();
     $( "#wrapper" ).css("width", "40px");
     $( "#flag" ).delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this behaviour this you can call `stop()` before you perform any further animations within each event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#flag").stop(true).fadeOut(150);
    $("#wrapper").css("width", "360px");
    $("#name").delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });

  $("#wrapper").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#name").stop(true).hide();
    $("#wrapper").css("width", "40px");
    $("#flag").delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });
});
```

```css
#flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#name {
  display: none;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% + 1px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  background: #e5515f;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="flag" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/flag-icon.svg">
  <img id="name" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/cftp-logo.svg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` to force an animation to finish before its duration.

```js
// Home button hover effects
$(document).ready(function () {
 if($(window).width() >= 576) {
  $( "#wrapper" ).mouseenter(function() {
   $( "#flag" ).finish().fadeOut(150);
   $( "#wrapper" ).css("width", "360px");
   $( "#name" ).finish().delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });
  $( "#wrapper" ).mouseleave(function() {
   $( "#name" ).finish().hide();
   $( "#wrapper" ).css("width", "40px");
   $( "#flag" ).finish().delay(150).fadeIn(150);
  });
 }
});
```

```css
#flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#name {
  display: none;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% + 1px);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.15s;
  background: #e5515f;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <img id="flag" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/flag-icon.svg">
  <img id="name" src="https://dev.creativeforthepeople.org/assets/globals/cftp-logo.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `stop()`? `end()` is to do with DOM traversal/jQuery method chaining.

Comment: i'm actually thinking of `finish()` @RoryMcCrossan